# How to collect data from a form and inset it in another sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Good afternoon,

I am creating an app using sharepoint and powerapps, on powerapps I have a form that feeds from a sharepoint list. Now my problem is the following, when I create a new form I would like to submit from another sharepoint because it is going to be easier for me to create reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have a Form tied to a Sharepoint List and you want to copy its contents to another Sharepoint List with the same column structure. Is that correct?

If that is so, this is how you do it:

1) Add both SharePoint Lists (List1 and List2) as DataSources to your app

2) Set your form's Data source to List1

3) Select the fields you want to edit

4) Add a button to your form. Set the OnSelect value of the button to this:

```
Patch( 'List2', Defaults( 'List2' ), { Column1: val1, Column2: val2, etc.. } )
```

where val1, val2 etc.. are values you entered into your controls 
Ex:  = txtFirstName.Text,  ddlStartDate.SelectedDate etc..

**NOTE**: Your column names have to match the exact spelling of the column names on List 2. If you have any multi word column names, put them in single quotes. Ex: 'First Name'

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-defaults